# Specify connection string for api in EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using the repository pattern using EF5 and I would like to specify the name of the connection string.

In my older EF projects I used to do this:

```
MyEntities _entities = new MyEntities("Name=MyConnectionString");
```

And when I created a new "api" that uses EF5 in VS2012 there is no overload for string argument.

I tried to do this:

```
private MyEntities _entities = new MyEntities ();

public MyRepository()
{
   _entities.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Name=MyConnectionString";
}
```

I get:

> "No connectionstring named 'MyEntities' could be found in the
>   application config file"

How should I give the repository a given connectionstring? Should I edit those code generation files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the only thing needed was a partial class to make it work.

Here is how I did it...

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
}
```

After that I was able to use:

```
MyEntities _entities = new MyEntities("Name=MyConnectionString");
```

Comment: partial?? but that simply means you extended the definition of the class ? you could have done that using a constructor??why doing it wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

make your `MyEntities` constructor like:

```
 public MyEntities()
            : base("MyConnectionString")
 { 

 }
```

and a more generic way:

```
 public MyEntities(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
```

assuming `MyEntities` class is the one which inherits `DbContext`

and use it like:

```
public MyRepository()
{
     using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
     {
     }

     //or
     using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities(connectionString))
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: "object does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument"

Comment: I believe it is `MyEntities` that inherits from `DbContext`.

Comment: see my answer now. modify it according to your architecture